# How to display format string for a second value of string?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, devexpress

I combine the two columns into one column, which is currency and value (USD 20000). Now I want to add the format string of the value, so it will be like this > USD 20,000. But how to add the `property.DisplayFormatString` on the second string.

I tried to add `property.DisplayFormatString = "0,0.00"` but it doesn't change the format

```
settings.Columns.Add(column =>
{
    column.FieldName = "Value";
    column.Caption = "Total";
    var property = column.PropertiesEdit as TextBoxProperties;

    column.SetDataItemTemplateContent(t =>
    {
        Html.DevExpress().Label(
        l => {
              l.Text = String.Format("{0} {1}", 
                  DataBinder.Eval(t.DataItem, "CurrencyCode"), 
                  DataBinder.Eval(t.DataItem, "Value"));
            property.DisplayFormatString = {"0,0.00"}
        }).Render();
    });
});
```

I expect the output of will be

> USD 20,000

but the actual output is

> USD 20000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the formatting within `string.Format` using format string `"{1:0,0.00}"`.

```
 l.Text = String.Format("{0} {1:0,0.00}", 
              DataBinder.Eval(t.DataItem, "CurrencyCode"), 
              DataBinder.Eval(t.DataItem, "Value"));
```

This will be displayed as `20,000.0`.  If you want without the decimal you can try `"{1:0,0}"` which should display `20,000`.

Answer (score 0):

You should change money format into database than fetch record in aspx page like this

SELECT Name,FORMAT(TotalAmount,'#,###,#0') from TableName

Answer (score 0):

You can use the currency format like `c`

`c` for `int` currency like 2,000

`c2` for decimal or float like 2,000.00

`c3` for decimal or float like 2,000.000

for more details, you can check this article [link](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpress.Web.EditPropertiesBase.DisplayFormatString.property)